# What is the overhead of dbt cloud’s dynamic model generation?

Tags: dbt

I am using **dbt cloud** and would like to know what happens in the backend when I generate model dynamically from the schema.

- Does it parse the schema file and generate sql statements ?
- If it parse the schema file, does it parse the whole file or just the part for which I want to generate the model ?

What is the overhead that I need to consider in general when generating model dynamically from the schema ?

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should ask one question. Yours currently asks four. Please edit your question to only ask one thing, or it risks being closed as 'needing focus' (see "needs more focus" section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: As well, "model dynamically from the schema" is very vague. An example of how this is happening would be helpful